# How can I achieve this effect of text bleeding into colors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

[image]

I've been trying to figure out how to get a similar result in photoshop but have had no luck.

Comment: If you spend enough time you can make it manually. Are you looking for an automated way to achieve that? Something like Photoshop Actions/Photoshop Effects?

Comment: Where does that image come from? It could be helpful in deciphering how it was created. Also can you [edit] to add some of your own images and describe where you're stuck? That way we could help you move forward with your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Start from a white on black drawing. 
Apply a bit of blur towards the bottom.

Then apply the liquify tool to the red green and blue channels separately with slightly different settings.

Then apply a hue-shift, for the analog look.

The orange glow near the bottom is done separately.